# mongoDb morphia POJO property with read only access

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo, morphia

I have created a POJO class in  morphia to save data object to MongoDB  ,

I have a property called 'unitPrice', i want to keep this as read only property, mean not allow to modify DB value once it save to mongo,
Is there a morphia annotation to do this or else,
Is it possible to bind @NotSaved annotation to the property at run time ?

This is my POJO

```
@Entity("items")  
public class Items  {
 private int id;
 private int sequence;
 private int unitPrice;  
}
```

Thanks
BR
Ero

Comment: To clarify, do you want the database to enforce that the `unitPrice` value cannot be modified once it has been saved? Or just that your Java code can't change it once it's been set?

Comment: i want to enforce the DB to keep initial value, without change it

Comment: MongoDB doesn't enforce restrictions on fields like that, with the sole exception that the `_id` for a document is immutable. Putting price in `_id` isn't reasonable, so you just need to make sure your applications don't modify the price field.

Comment: Thanks wdberkeley, but i'm accessing mongo via morphia, i want to know is there a way to do it from morphia ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to bind `@NotSaved` at runtime, but I could think of a (hacky) workaround:

- Set the attribute in the constructor (Morphia will still require the no-args constructor)
- Don't provide a setter, just a getter for the attribute

It ain't pretty, but it should get the job done.